# Javascript dynamic filter over js with array of criterions

Tags: javascript, filter

```
const arr = [
   {label : 'lbl1', text: 'txt1'},
   {label : 'lbl2', text: 'txt2'},
   {label : 'lbl3', text: 'txt3'},
   {label : 'lbl4', text: 'txt4'},
   // much more items
];

const filterBy = [
    {label: 'lbl1',text: 'txt1'},
    {label : 'lbl4', text: 'txt4'}
    //may have 0 or more items
];
```

I want to **dynamically** filter `arr` by `filterBy`. `filterBy` is coming from the UI... here its just a representation of what the user can pass...

in a static way I would do:

```
arr.filter(x => (x.text == filterBy[0].text && x.label == filterBy[0].label) ||
   .            (x.text == filterBy[1].text && x.label == filterBy[1].label)
);
```

Is it possible to chain dynamic criterions in JS?
Thanks

Comment: You mean that `filterBy` can also have not 2, but many items in it?

Comment: @ZoliSzabó yes. exactly.

Comment: `filterBy`  is already a filtered version of `arr`

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath `filterBy` is something the use pass to, to it is totally dynamic

Comment: There can be many properties in `filterBy` and `arr` should be filtered by it. Is that right?

Comment: `arr` and `filterBy` (not groupBy) are totally dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const arr = [
  { label: "lbl1", text: "txt1" },
  { label: "lbl2", text: "txt2" },
  { label: "lbl3", text: "txt3" },
  { label: "lbl4", text: "txt4" },
];

const filterBy = [
  { label: "lbl1", text: "txt1" },
  { label: "lbl4", text: "txt4" },
];

const result = arr.filter(({ label, text }) =>
  filterBy.some((o) => o.label === label && o.text === text)
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce and inside the callback use filter to get the items from `arr`

```js
const arr = [{
    label: 'lbl1',
    text: 'txt1'
  },
  {
    label: 'lbl2',
    text: 'txt2'
  },
  {
    label: 'lbl3',
    text: 'txt3'
  },
  {
    label: 'lbl4',
    text: 'txt4'
  },
  //.... much more items
];

const filterBy = [{
    label: 'lbl1',
    text: 'txt1'
  },
  {
    label: 'lbl4',
    text: 'txt4'
  }
];


const res = filterBy.reduce((acc, curr) => {

  acc.push(...arr.filter(item => {
    return item.label === curr.label && item.text === curr.text
  }))

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

use an obj instead of an array

```js
const arr = [
   {label : 'lbl1', text: 'txt1'},
   {label : 'lbl2', text: 'txt2'},
   {label : 'lbl3', text: 'txt3'},
   {label : 'lbl4', text: 'txt4'},
];

const filterBy = {
  criteria1:"lbl1",
  criteria2:"txt1",
  criteria3:"lbl4",
  criteria4:"txt2",
}

const filtered = arr.filter(item => filterBy["criteria1"] === item.label ||filterBy["criteria2"] === item.text)||filterBy["criteria3"] === item.label || filterBy["criteria4"] === item.text);
```

the other "solutions" have to make two or plus loops. while this one only do one.

while more criterias you have, the uglier it is going to look like

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
   {label : 'lbl1', text: 'txt1'},
   {label : 'lbl2', text: 'txt2'},
   {label : 'lbl3', text: 'txt3'},
   {label : 'lbl4', text: 'txt4'},
   // much more items
];

const filterBy = [
    {label: 'lbl1',text: 'txt1'},
    {label : 'lbl4', text: 'txt4'}
    //may have 0 or more items
];

// If you want `||` between the filters.
console.log(arr.filter(x => filterBy.some(f => f.label === x.label && f.text === x.text)));

// If you want `&&` between the filters.
console.log(arr.filter(x => filterBy.every(f => f.label === x.label && f.text === x.text)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wants.. dynamic criterias.. using Object.keys and reduce you can get this.

```js
const arr = [
   {label : 'lbl1', text: 'txt1'},
   {label : 'lbl2', text: 'txt2'},
   {label : 'lbl3', text: 'txt3'},
   {label : 'lbl4', text: 'txt4'},
   // much more items
];

const filterBy = [
    {label: 'lbl1',text: 'txt1'},
    {label : 'lbl4', text: 'txt4'}
];

const filtered = arr.filter(item => {
    return filterBy.some(fItem => {
           const keys = Object.keys(fItem);
           return keys.length > 0 && keys.reduce((acc, k) => {
            return acc && item[k] === fItem[k];
           }, true)
    });
});

console.log(filtered)
```